# Why dynamic values are not being submitted from form with NextJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, formik, chakra-ui

I'm working on React based on NextJS code.

If I manually enter values in form fields and submit the form, I get all the values in the component function.

But if I dynamically display values in a form field like `value={query.campaignid}`, the component does not collect any value.

```
import { Button, Input } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { Field, Form, Formik } from "formik";

import { useRouter } from "next/router";

export default function FormikExample() {
  const { query } = useRouter();

  return (
    <>
      <Formik
        initialValues={
          {
            // campaignid: " ",
          }
        }
        onSubmit={(values) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(values);
          });
        }}
      >
        {(props) => (
          <Form>
            <Field name="campaignid">
              <Input value={query.campaignid} />
            </Field>

            <Button id="submited" isLoading={props.isSubmitting} type="submit">
              Submit
            </Button>
          </Form>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved!

I passed the URL query to `initialValues` and added `enableReinitialize={true}` below:

```
...
     initialValues={{
        campaignId: query.campaignid,         
     }}
     enableReinitialize={true}
...
```

In the input value I passed those props:

```
 <Field name="campaignid">
       <Input value={props.values.campaignId} />
  </Field>
```